# How to define an array of anonymous method

Tags: delphi

I want to define an array of anonymous method: `TFunc<Integer>`:

```
function MyFunc: Integer;
begin

end;

procedure TForm84.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var A: TArray<TFunc<Integer>>;
begin
  A := [MyFunc];
end;
```

But Delphi compiler prompt error:

```
[dcc32 Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.SysUtils.TFunc<System.Integer>' and 'Integer'
```

Using array for native data type like `integer` or `string` works for similar construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler isn't able to decide whether your use of `MyFunc` means to call the function or to refer to it as function.

So you'll likely need to help the compiler out:

```
SetLength(A, 1);
A[0] := MyFunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyFunc()` does not take any input parameters, so Delphi allows it to optionally be called without parenthesis, eg:

```
var
  I: Integer;

I := MyFunc();
I := MyFunc; // <-- same as above!
```

In a statement like `A := [MyFunc];`, the compiler is apparently not smart enough to figure out that the context in which `MyFunc` is used requires the *address* of `MyFunc()` to be passed to the array, and so it instead *calls* `MyFunc()` and passes the return value to the array, hence the error message.

So, you need to be more explicit to the compiler that the address is needed.

Try this:

```
A := [@MyFunc];
```

Or:

```
A := [Addr(MyFunc)];
```

Or:

```
type
  TIntFuncArray := TArray<TFunc<Integer>>;
var
  A: TIntFuncArray;
begin
  A := TIntFuncArray.Create(MyFunc); // or maybe @ or Addr(), not sure
end;
```